# PHP All Function Variables Global

Tags: php, variables, global-variables, global

I have a function called init on my website in an external file called functions.php. Index.php loads that page and calls function init:

```
function init(){
   error_reporting(0);
   $time_start = microtime(true);
   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","user123","password123");
   mysql_select_db("db123");
}
```

How can I get all of these variables global(if possible) without having to use

```
global $time_start;
global $con;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specifically use globals, take a look at [$GLOBALS](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php) array. Even though there are couple of other ways, *[Pass by reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)*, *[Data Registry Object](http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.registry.using.html)*  <sup>recommended</sup>, etc.

*[More on variable scopes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)*.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want it global.

On alternative is to encapsulate it in a object or even use a DI in order to configure it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can return these variables from your init() function :

```
function init(){
   error_reporting(0);
   $time_start = microtime(true);
   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","user123","password123");
   mysql_select_db("db123");

   return array('time_start' => $time_start, 'con' => $con);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare them in the global scope, then pass them to the function by reference.  *After modifying the function to do so.*